# Redirect Page Using Puppeteer While Keeping cache?

Tags: javascript, npm

So I have some code written in `javascript` that opens a page and logs in. After `puppeteer` is done logging in, I want it to `redirect` to a different page on the site while keeping the cache. I have tried doing  `page.goto(url);` but that clears the cache.
Any answers are welcome.

Comment: did you try `page
.goBack()` to return to that page

Comment: I want it to go to a different page that it hasn't visited before.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace

Refer the mdn documentation

> The replace() method of the Location interface replaces the current resource with the one at the provided URL.

```
window.location.replace("http://" + ipAddr + ":" + port + "/");
```

to redirect to a different page

Comment: I tried to do this, but it did not do anything to the page. I'm using puppeteer to control a webpage.